# frozen list as partition key in Cassandra is a good practice or any alternates

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have created a table & primary key type is set.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace1.list_by_account 
    (id uuid, name text,
     account frozen <set<text>>, 
     PRIMARY KEY (account, id));
```

is this a good way to find later on entries from it?

Below query will scan all partitions or will directly find partitions on base of IN parameters?

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace1.list_by_account WHERE account IN ?
```

Last thing when I run below query, this does not return any data:

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace1.list_by_account WHERE account CONTAINS 'private_account1';
```

Currently I am using Cassandra 2.1.14.

Comment: your `create table` isn't correct - names in primary key doesn't match columns

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt edited.